# How to know as soon as a pointer is copied?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, valgrind

I have a dynamically allocated memory to a pointer. Some part of code copy this pointer to many containers, but I am not aware of the exact containers. Is it possible to know (may be by registering callback or something) whenever a pointer is copied in any container (i.e. shallow copy)?

If anyone can suggest a way to achieve this through some code addition or through Valgrind.

Code

```
int *arr[1];
void func(int* p)
{
    arr[0] = p;
}

void PrintArray()
{
    cout<<arr[0]<<endl;    //This is a stale pointer
}

int main()
{
    int* p = new int(10);
    func(p);
    delete p;
    PrintArray();
    return 0;
}
```

In above code, 'p' is allocated memory in main function, and this pointer copied to array in 'func' function. Now in 'PrintArray' i am printing this array while its data is already deleted.

This is a simple case where in know the container is array. So i can handle it, but in my code base being it very large there can be many containers where i have such pointers, and accessing those giving me problems. How can i find those containers, other then again stumbling into codebase?

Comment: Have a look at shared_ptr and weak_ptr

Comment: Description is quite vague. Maybe it would be better show some code to explain what you are trying to achieve. My first guess would also `weak_ptr`, but when I'm reading your description again I have doubts.

Comment: Take a look at reference counting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting
And `std::shared_ptr` which is based on it.

Comment: A raw pointer?  No.  You can make a wrapper around a pointer (a *smart pointer*, of sorts) that can have extra behavior such as you want.

Comment: ***Is it possible to know (may be by registering callback or something) whenever a pointer is copied in any container (i.e. shallow copy)?*** You will have to make your own pointer class for that

Comment: @MarekR I have added a sample code to describe it more.

Comment: Better yet, avoid using owning pointers in public interfaces. Then the whole issue is avoided.

Comment: If this is a large code base that you did not write yourself you probably will have to use a tool to analyze the memory allocations for you. I am not sure you just want to go in and start replacing pointers with smart pointers everywhere there are design reasons to choose between which smart pointer to use and why.

Comment: @drescherjm I am sure that will solve some mysterious bugs they have had for years :-)

Comment: @drescherjm No, i am afraid, i can;t change pointer type as of now. I am looking for a way to analyze and get a way to find this.

Comment: Based on edit you have to watch this https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE (your issue is covered and in nicely explained by C++ standard committee member)

Answer (score 3):

`std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` are what you want:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  auto pc = std::make_shared<char>('a');

  std::printf("use count = %zu\n", pc.use_count());

  auto pc2 = pc;

  std::printf("use count = %zu\n", pc.use_count());

  {
    auto pc3 = pc;
    std::printf("use count = %zu\n", pc.use_count());
  }

  std::printf("use count = %zu\n", pc.use_count());
}
```

Output:

```
use count = 1
use count = 2
use count = 3
use count = 2
```

It will also manage the memory. Also pay attention to `std::weak_ptr` if you want to have a [weak reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference).